# is there a way to know the length of a bytearray variable in python?

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
variable = "FFFF"
message = bytearray( variable.decode("hex") )
```

after this, I want to perform something like this:

```
message.len()
```

but it seems that bytearray does not have something like "len()" implemented, is it possible to know the lenght?

Comment: Does `len(message)` not work?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The idiom used for this in python is `len(obj)`, not `obj.len()`

```
>>> v = 'ffff'
>>> msg = bytearray(v.decode('hex'))
>>> len(msg)
2
```

If you are creating your own class that should be able to report its length, implement the magic method `__len__(self)`, which will be called when the built-in function `len()` is called and passed an instance of your class.

### Why?

See [this old post](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-does-python-use-methods-for-some-functionality-e-g-list-index-but-functions-for-other-e-g-len-list.htm) from Guido:

> (a) For some operations, prefix notation just reads better than
>   postfix — prefix (and infix!) operations have a long tradition in
>   mathematics which likes notations where the visuals help the
>   mathematician thinking about a problem. Compare the easy with which we
>   rewrite a formula like x*(a+b) into x*a + x*b to the clumsiness of
>   doing the same thing using a raw OO notation.
>
> (b) When I read code that says len(x) I know that it is asking for the
>   length of something. This tells me two things: the result is an
>   integer, and the argument is some kind of container. To the contrary,
>   when I read x.len(), I have to already know that x is some kind of
>   container implementing an interface or inheriting from a class that
>   has a standard len().