# Python array length shorter than declared

Tags: python, arrays

I noticed that array length is twice shorter than I declare.
The code is as below:

```
import array

a = array.array('H', bytearray(1000))
print(len(a))
```

As I understand I declare array length 1000 but its length is 500. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: The 500 and 1000 are in different units.  Check the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an answer from another question:
[is there a way to know the length of a bytearray variable in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29304342/is-there-a-way-to-know-the-length-of-a-bytearray-variable-in-python/29304376)

#### In your case:

The **len()** function returns an integer value that is equal to the number of elements present in that array.
Since you're declaring an array on bytes without a content, you're only allocating bytes; and as Prune suggests, you have to choose *your* numeric value since you're working on bytes. You have to check the documentation of array module and select the correct "Type code" that you want to use.

*https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html*

Comment: Actually the "Type code" changes the array elements but it is still maximum half of declared. Is there any trick to solve it?